# Clickable link not displaying with programmatically created custom UITextView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I want to get hyperlink in UITextView and with tap gesture I'm enabling textView.isEditable = true. But the link is not displaying in UITextView.
I have a custom TextView which I'm calling in ViewController.

Here's my code:

```
 var textView: TextView?

override public func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 
    textView = TextView(
      editorConfig: EditorConfig(
        theme: getTheme()
      )
    )
  }
 override public func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    view.backgroundColor = .white

    layoutTextView()
}
private func layoutTextView() {
    textView?.frame = CGRect(
      x: view.safeAreaInsets.left,
      y: view.safeAreaInsets.top,
      width: view.bounds.width - view.safeAreaInsets.left - view.safeAreaInsets.right,
      height: view.frame.size.height / 3
    )

    textView?.layer.borderWidth = 1
    textView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    textView?.isEditable = false
    textView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    textView?.textColor = .black
    textView?.dataDetectorTypes = .link
    textView?.text = "https://www.google.com"
    
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(textViewTapped))
    textView?.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
  }

@objc func textViewTapped(_ aRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    textView?.dataDetectorTypes = []
      textView?.isEditable = true
      textView?.becomeFirstResponder()
  }
  
  func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
      textView.isEditable = false
      textView.dataDetectorTypes = .all
  }

private func addAllSubviews() {
    if let textView = textView {
      view.addSubview(textView)
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You've created the text view and formatted it, but never actually added it to the superview, so it isn't displayed.  To fix this, try adding `view.addSubview(textView!)` at the end of your `layoutTextView()` function.  This will add your text view to the View Hierarchy, allowing it to be displayed.

Comment: I'd assume you're assigning the `textView` optional variable to an instance of your custom class inside viewDidLoad, and then calling `layoutTextView()` inside viewDidLayoutSubviews?

Comment: Have you tried temporarily replacing your custom text view with a default `UITextView` (leaving everything else the same) and seeing if it displays the link for you?  I tested it with a default UITextView and it was displaying fine, as @VoidAsif has confirmed in the answer.  If this fixes the problem, it might be something to do with the custom text view implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Please provide all information regarding your code as you are using custom class of UITextview.

Declaration of textview i did as

```
var textView = UITextView()
```

I tested your code with Default UITextview and as @Quack E. Duck says you just need to add below code and you are done.

```
view.addSubview(textView)
```